# how to cluster numbers using java

Tags: java

I need your help in suggesting where I've gone wrong in my code. Actually, what I want is to form clusters using document pairs. There are nearly 1000 pairs of numbers in my text file, so it has to take the 1st pair as input and has to store it in an array, and now it should take 2nd pair and check whether either of the elements is present or not. If only one element exists in the array already, then it has to add the other element to the same array. If both the elements do not exist in the array, then they have to be stored in the new array.

sample input:
(23,7)
(11,23)
(1,5)
(67,5)
(34,17)

output:
(23,7,11)
(1,5,67)
(34,17)

My problem is that I'm not able to take the input from the text file as it is integers, but to split the text file it should be strings. My second problem is that I'm not able to store it in another array. Once the array is declared, the elements are getting overwritten. 
dis is my code which i have written to store the numbers in a array list but i am not able to store the elements in another array i dont know where to declare the new array list

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
a.add(i);
a.add(j);
if (!a.contains(i) && !a.contains(j))
{
    a.add(i);
    a.add(j);
    System.out.println("the cluster is" +a);
}
else if(a.contains(i) && !a.contains(j))
{
    a.add(j);
    System.out.println("the cluster is" +a);
}
else if(!a.contains(i) && a.contains(j))
{
    a.add(i);
    System.out.println("the cluster is" +a);
}
```

Comment: You could at least use punctuation and correct spelling.... If you show no effort to help us understand your question, why would we help you?

Comment: Please add some of these to your text: ,,,...;;;

Comment: Also, this site is about programming issues.  What have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: Okay, much better.  Showing some effort helps.  I'm upvoting so this to lessen its negative rating, and supplying a partial answer. See below.

Answer (score 0):

1) It doesn't matter that they're integers.  Your "i" and "j" variables above can be of String for this purpose.
2) Your single ArrayList will never hold this kind of information.  There are options to consider, but the most straightforward is an array-of-arrays:
`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> pairs = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ();`.
In this, each element of the outer list is an array of strings - the same as your desired output.
Then, your code would look more like this:

```
// For each inner array in the outer array,
//    check to see if it contains either, neither, or both of i or j 
//    If it contains one, add the other to the inner array
//    Else if it contains neither, make a new array of strings and add that to the outer array
```

Try that, and if you get stuck again, come back and ask.

Comment: hey thanks for your suggestions i have started coding from first and i dont know how to take input 4 29 from a text file

Comment: because they have to be the i,j values for which the input has to be taken at once and check in the array list and also as you suggested to use arraylist<arraylist<string>> after declaring the array list i am not able to add the i,j values to the arraylist the error it is showing is method is not applicable

Comment: @user2199808 what does the code look like now, and what line is getting an error?  As to not knowing how to read strings from a text file, I'm surprised your teacher has thrown you into this assignment without covering the basics of file input.  Try this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html